# local development on localhost webapp and localhost access blocked by Cors policy

Tags: javascript, express, cors, localhost, fetch

I'm trying to develop both a web app and and api but I'm running in to cors blocking.
This is a little new to me, but I would like to be better.

So I have an express server for the api:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()

module.exports = app.post('/posttest/', cors(), async (req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.json({ msg: 'WHOAH with CORS it works!' })
})
```

This is served locally on http://localhost:3000
"posttest" is the above module for my route.

```
const posttest = require('./src/routes/posttest.js')
const server = require('http').createServer();
const { Router } = require('express');

server
  .on(
    'request',
    Router({ mergeParams: true })
    .use( posttest )
  )
  .on('listening', () =>{
    console.log('listeing');
  })
  .on('error', () => {
    console.log('ERROR!!!!');
  })
  .listen(3000);
```

Then I have my web app that makes a Post request using fetch:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/posttest/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({text:'test'}),
    mode: 'cors' }) .then( (res) => {   //resolve }) .catch( (err) => {   //error    });
```

I should also mention that the web app is being served locally on localhost:8080

So the problem is that when I try to make a post request I get the

> following error. Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/posttest/'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

For what its worth I'm using chrome. 
So whats going on here? I thought that if I included `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');` It would solve my problems. Postman can successfully access the route. But when I use the browser it gets denied. The same thing happens If I put the server and web app into production. What am I missing? Could you explain it like I'm five?

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: You don't have to manually set `res.headers`, thats what `cors()` is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [pre-flight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) is an `OPTIONS` request, and your `cors()` handler is only attached to `POST` requests (through `.post`). Use

```
  app.use(cors());
```

to disable CORS globally (and answer pre-flights). You can also [enable pre-flight requests](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight) for a single route:

```
  app.options("/posttest/", cors());
  app.post('/posttest/', cors(), async (req, res, next) => {  
   res.json({ msg: 'WHOAH with CORS it works!' });
  });
```

Comment: Thank you. What I also noticed is that instead of using 'Content-Type': 'application/json', I use 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' or text/plain it works. The security concern is flagged by trying to use json right?